# Clipping two rasters with several polygon features - saving output rasters according to a field name in the polygon layer?

Tags: arcpy

I am an Economists and I am new to GIS. I am using ArcGIS for desktop 10.6. I am trying to clip a raster with several polygon features - saving output rasters according to a field name in the polygon layer.

I used the code by Midavalo. The code is running perfectly but the problem is that it gives me an output of light raster for one province out of 200 I have in my field, it looks like it does not loop through i. It has been 2 months working on this but I get no help.

```
import arcpy, os

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\Users\Somaqaqa\Desktop\jupyter_python-tutorial1\installPycharm_pythonscript+\creating a file database\GiSPython_China\just_rastes"

clipshapefile = r"C:\Users\Somaqaqa\Desktop\jupyter_python-tutorial1\installPycharm_pythonscript+\creating a file database\GiSPython_China\Data\chn_admbnda_adm1_ocha.shp"

rasterlist = arcpy.ListRasters()

clipshapes = set() with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(clipshapefile, ['ADM1_EN']) as cursor:

for row in cursor:
     clipshapes.add(row[0])
Loop through input rasters, and clip by each shape in the input shapefile
for raster in rasterlist:

rastername, rasterext = os.path.splitext(raster)
for i in clipshapes:

    newRaster = "{}_FID{}.tif".format(rastername, i)
    newRasterPath = os.path.join(outputWorkspace, newRaster)
    Cliplayer = "Ras {}".format(raster)

 if arcpy.Exists('ClipLayer'):

arcpy.Delete_management('ClipLayer')
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(clipshapefile, Cliplayer, " ADM1_EN = '{}'".format(i))

arcpy.Clip_management(raster, "#", newRasterPath, Cliplayer, "0", "ClippingGeometry", 
"MAINTAIN_EXTENT")
print raster

print i
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the nested loop (all the clipping should be in the internal loop). I'm not sure how your file is idented because when I copy your code and paste in my IDE it shows many identation problems. Anyway, after fixing these problems and adding the output workspace (It is missing in the sample given), I tested it with 2 rasters and 3 shapefiles and had a output of 6 rasters:

```
import arcpy, os

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

arcpy.env.workspace = 'C:\\Teste\\raster\\Desmatamento_Maryland'

clipshapefile = 'C:\\Teste\\shp\\Test_Clip_Maryland.shp'

outputWorkspace = 'C:\\Teste\\raster\\output'

rasterlist = arcpy.ListRasters()

clipshapes = set()

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(clipshapefile, ['ADM1_EN']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        clipshapes.add(row[0])

#Loop through input rasters, and clip by each shape in the input shapefile
for raster in rasterlist:
    rastername, rasterext = os.path.splitext(raster)

    for i in clipshapes:
        newRaster = "{}_FID{}.tif".format(rastername, i)
        newRasterPath = os.path.join(outputWorkspace, newRaster)
        Cliplayer = "Ras {}".format(raster)

        if arcpy.Exists('ClipLayer'):
            arcpy.Delete_management('ClipLayer')

        arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(clipshapefile, Cliplayer, " ADM1_EN = '{}'".format(i))

        arcpy.Clip_management(raster, "#", newRasterPath, Cliplayer, "0", "ClippingGeometry", 
        "MAINTAIN_EXTENT")
        print raster

        print i

print 'End of script'
```